# Subtract datetime from two columns and put result as integer in third

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have 2 datetime columns in a table and I want to subtract each row one from another and somehow put results in new 3rd column rows as int.

I know I have to use `DATEFIFF` somehow, but what confuses me even more how do I parse each row of a table (while loop perhaps)?

Thank you!

Comment: You're not thinking like SQL, it uses a set based approach, not a cursor based approach. You an just add the DATEDIFF function in the select statement and it will apply for each row in the table.

Comment: Tag dbms used! (datediff is product specific functionality.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example to go by from SQL 2008 assuming Date1Column and Date2Column are datetime fields.  I gave a few examples showing delta between dates in minutes, days, months.

```
Select

    ,CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, Date1Column, Date2Column) as int) as 'DeltaMinutes'
    ,CAST(DATEDIFF(day, Date1Column, Date2Column) as int) as 'DeltaDays'
    ,ISNULL(DATEDIFF(MONTH, Date1Column, Date2Column), -9999) as 'LastSWAge'

From Table
```

Comment: Thanks it was helpfull.